# DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule in an ASP.NET WebForms application?

Tags: api, asp.net-4.0, httpmodule

Can I use [DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.infrastructure.dynamicmodulehelper.dynamicmoduleutility.registermodule.aspx) in an ASP.NET WebForms application?  It seems not, but I'm just confused, as many pages I've found in searching cite its availability w/ "ASP.NET 4.0".

Comment: Sure you can. I use it a lot. Why do you think you can not, anyway?

Comment: Reading I'd done at the time gave me that impression. Nothing more.